# .NET - Process started by Windows Service is killed prematurely if the service runs as LocalSystem (as opposed to Administrator)

Tags: .net, process, windows-installer

This has driven me crazy for the last 2 days. I am trying to do a very simple updater for a Windows service of ours. The idea is the following:

- the service knows it must update itself; it starts the updater using Process.Start
- the updater downloads the new .msi, uninstalls the current application and installs the new application

Worth noting: the installer is part of the application so it is also removed/reinstalled as part of the process.

**The problem**: the updater process stops immediately after the application is uninstalled.

At first I figured it would make sense that the updater is killed if the exe is deleted or if its caller (the windows service) is killed. But: if the service runs as an Administrator instead of LocalSystem, then it all works perfectly! Why? I can't figure this out.

The code in the windows service that starts the updater:

```
Dim tProcess As New Process
tProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "ServiceUpdater.exe"
tProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
tProcess.Start()
```

In the ServiceUpdater.exe, the code that uninstalls and reinstalls the service:

```
LogWindowsEvent("Now uninstalling.", Nothing, EventLogEntryType.Information)
Uninstall()
LogWindowsEvent("Uninstalled. Now installing.", Nothing, EventLogEntryType.Information)
Install()
LogWindowsEvent("Installed.", Nothing, EventLogEntryType.Information)
```

- When the service (and therefore the updater?) runs as LocalSystem, the "Uninstalled" log is never printed
- When the service (and therefore the updater?) runs as Administrator, all logs are printed

In case it matters, the Uninstall function:

```
Private Sub Uninstall()
    Process.Start("msiexec.exe", "/x{" & "7E59BCD2-0DDC-4653-9AFF-15126A5C811E" & "} /quiet").WaitForExit()
End Sub
```

What's going on here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work by copying the application files to a temporary folder and running the ServiceUpdater from this folder. Obviously the updater was stopping when the exe file was deleted (when run by LocalSystem) so this let it run to completion. I then clear the temporary folder.

This does not explain why the updater stops when the exe is deleted when run by LocalSystem but not by Administrator - but it works good enough to me for now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be related to ADMIN RIGHTS necessary to delete files at specific service/folder.

Nicholas, I guess your problem should be solved in any way if you change the logic of the update.

The update must NOT uninstall the service but, stops it and replace it with the new module.

For this, you must call another application, that will provide these actions: stop your service, copy the new module over it, restart your service.

Comment: I wanted to avoid that as the only thing I have available right now is the service installer (msi) and did not want to have to create and expose a zip file containing the files to update. However when run as LocalSystem all files are deleted (including ServiceUpdater.exe).

Comment: The problem is some antivirus block your upgrade to run as LocalSystem, perhaps one of the greatest level of priviledge. Your ZIP can be encrypted with a HUGE password or even you may utilize another compression tool. Anyway, I believe the most common way utilized by many applications (as I describe above) may reflects the best solution to your case, face to many problems related to this update. Good luck.